# Need HTML & CSS for simple 3 buttons in a DIV

Tags: html, css, button

I have created a webpage with a google map embedded and need some code for 3 buttons in a div below the map, i have tried a few things yet nothing seems to work, they need to be inline e.g  [BUTTON 1]    [BUTTON 2]    [BUTTON 3]

Comment: Noone will be able to help you with that little information and no code.

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why  it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time  to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers,  and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer!  See also: [ask]

Answer (score 1):

Did you try adding 3 buttons to your html? I think it will give you the desired result

```html
<div>
  <button>Button 1</button>
  <button>Button 2</button>
  <button>Button 3</button>
</div>
```